# GridView with Checkbox in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I am use Visual Studio 2008 to coding ASP.NET in C#

I am trying to get value checked or unchecked form checkbox in Gridview.
This is my code to do.

```
void imbTransferBySelect_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Transfer_Selector");
        if (cb.Checked)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

When the checkbox is unchecked the code runs fine.

But when checkbox is checked value of `GridView1.Rows.Count = 0` it's make for loop is fail

I try use another code in http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GridView-with-CheckBox-Get-Selected-Rows-in-ASPNet.aspx

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("Transfer_Selector") as CheckBox);
        if (chkRow.Checked)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

It's runs fine when check-box is not checked.

And when check-box checked it's make loop in for-each fail again.

Anyone ever had a problem like me or know what's happened.

Comment: What means "when checkbox is checked value of GridView1.Rows.Count = 0 it's make for loop is fail"? How can a checkbox be checked if there is no row with a `CheckBox`?

Comment: Yes, when check-box checked the GridView1.Rows.Count = 0, I see it in debug step, and when code run finished the gridview is missing

Comment: I try to change check-box default is checked in .aspx file and run again, it's fail again but when i unchecked all, it's can run in for loop and it's enter the checked condition. Sorry for my problem, It should make you confuse.

Comment: Can you put your gridview html in your code. Aslo the code where you binding gridview.

Answer (score 1):

Buddy just put one `if` condition on `foreach` loop according to your question i am giving you solution. check below solution..

```
if(GridView1.Rows.Count > 0 )
{
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("Transfer_Selector") as CheckBox);
        if (chkRow.Checked)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `GridView1.Rows.Count = 0` and it's not enter to the condition

Comment: you just add this condition -> if(GridView1.Rows.Count > 0 )

Comment: I coding like this and when i running `GridView1.Rows.Count = 0` so it's not enter to if and for-each condition.

Comment: What you want to do? exactly??!!

Comment: I want to get name from checked row  and change they managerID from database